# T-SQL: Convert money to float

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

How can I convert `(money/int)*100` to a `float` datatype?

`a.ResidualValue` is of type `money`, while `ListPriceCar` is of type `int`.

The following outputs a number with a comma as the decimal separator, so I presume it is still a `money` field, and not a `float` as I wish:

```
CONVERT(float, CONVERT(float, REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), a.ResidualValue), ',', '.'))/ListPriceCar)*100 AS 'Residual value %'
```

Result: 62,825

Comment: Please show us some sample data , with expected and actual results.

Answer (score 0):

What is issue with simple cast as below:

```
DECLARE @money AS money
SET @money = $2345234.35
SELECT @money, CAST(@money AS float)
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of ResidualValue? If ResidualValue contains a comma, then comma is your decimal char. You shouldn't convert it into a point then. You can divide a money value by an int value.

```
declare @a money = 10.5;
declare @b int = 20;

select (@a / @b) * 100
select cast((@a / @b) * 100 as float)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the result was already given as an float. You can test this by running the following example code.

```
--INPUT VARIABLES
declare @ResidualValue money = 5000.54
declare @ListPriceCar int = 15000
--OUTPUT VARIABLE
declare @ResultCalculation as sql_variant;
--CALCULATION
set @ResultCalculation = CONVERT(float, CONVERT(float, REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @ResidualValue), ',', '.'))/@ListPriceCar)*100 
--GET INFORMATION ON THE OUTPUT VARIABLE
select sql_variant_property(@ResultCalculation,'BaseType') AS 'Base Type',
       sql_variant_property(@ResultCalculation,'Precision') AS 'Precision',
       sql_variant_property(@ResultCalculation,'Scale') AS 'Scale',
       sql_variant_property(@ResultCalculation,'TotalBytes') AS 'TotalBytes',
       sql_variant_property(@ResultCalculation,'Collation') AS 'Collation',
       sql_variant_property(@ResultCalculation,'MaxLength') AS 'MaxLength';
```

[image]

There is an easier way to calculate your answer:

```
CAST(@ResidualValue/@ListPriceCar * 100 as float)
```